# Photo tagging system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery system (and user database) built in ASP.NET and I want to add a tagging feature like Facebook.
There must be some kind of photo tagging system, and I don't want to write my own from the beginning.

Can somebody please target me for a code providing this feature or help me where should I start writing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching like this free open source script.

[FotoNotes](http://www.fotonotes.net/)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.thesmarttagger.com

I think there you can get javascript solution for image tag. they are providing example with PHP. You will need to change it to .net.